# VS Code default keybinding `shift+cmd+left` for `cursorHomeSelect` action not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been hoping to make the jump from Atom to VS Code, but I cannot seem to get some of VS Code's default bindings to work on my machine. The same shortcuts work perfectly in Atom. This is driving me crazy, so would be curious if others have had a similar issue with getting this to work.

My machine: `macOS Sierra (v10.12.6)` running `VS Code (v1.25.1)`.

[Screenshot from VS Code Keyboard Shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZsgb.png)

The default keybinding information:

```
{
  "key": "shift+cmd+left",
  "command": "cursorHomeSelect",
  "when": "textInputFocus"
},
```

The same issue occurs for the default `cursorEndSelect` command, with key binding `shift+cmd+right`. The alternative key bindings for these two commands (`shift+Home` and `shift+End`, respectively) seem to work.

**UPDATE:**
I've noticed that this binding will work temporarily when first loading up VS Code, and this is the first binding I attempt. But once I do some other action (most recently, it was `cursorUpSelect`/`shift+up`), it stops working properly. I have colleagues with similar setups as me, and this action works perfectly fine for them. I thought it may be SizeUp that is hijacking that binding, but I've disabled this app and it still is an issue.

Comment: Odd that on my Windows machine, cursorHomeSelect only has the one (shift+Home) binding.  And Ctrl-Shift-left is bound to cursorWordStartLeftSelect.

Comment: @Mark I also have that binding for the same action on my Mac, and it works fine. Other `cursorSelect` actions seem to work fine, it's just this one that wants to be difficult...

Comment: Any update on this? I've the same problem here, `shift+cmd+left` and `shift+cmd+right` are not working but otoh `shift+Home` and `shift+End` works like a charm.

Comment: @r0sk I ended up figuring out what my particular issue was. On my Mac, under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control, I had changed some of the default mappings. For "Move left a space" / "Move right a space" — I changed these to `cmd+left` / `cmd+right`, respectively. Looks like using `cmd` here was causing issues with VS Code. I updated these mappings to use `ctrl` instead and everything is back to normal!

Comment: I have exactly the same shortcuts, `cmd+left` and `cmd+right` to switch over the virtual desktops. I'll try, thank you so much for the tip.